# Efficient side-effect-only analogue of Clojure's map function

Tags: clojure

What if `map` and `doseq` had a baby? I'm trying to write a function or macro like Common Lisp's `mapc`, but in Clojure.  This does essentially what `map` does, but *only* for side-effects, so it doesn't need to generate a sequence of results, and wouldn't be lazy.  I know that one can iterate over a single sequence using `doseq`, but map can iterate over multiple sequences, applying a function to each element in turn of all of the sequences.  I also know that one can wrap `map` in `dorun`.  (Note: This question has been extensively edited after many comments and a very thorough answer.  The original question focused on macros, but those macro issues turned out to be peripheral.)

This is fast (according to criterium):

```
(defn domap2
  [f coll]
  (dotimes [i (count coll)]
    (f (nth coll i))))
```

but it only accepts one collection.  This accepts arbitrary collections:

```
(defn domap3
  [f & colls]
  (dotimes [i (apply min (map count colls))]
    (apply f (map #(nth % i) colls))))
```

but it's very slow by comparison.  I could also write a version like the first, but with different parameter cases `[f c1 c2]`, `[f c1 c2 c3]`, etc., but in the end, I'll need a case that handles arbitrary numbers of collections, like the last example, which is simpler anyway.  I've tried many other solutions as well.

Since the second example is very much like the first except for the use of `apply` and the `map` inside the loop, I suspect that getting rid of them would speed things up a lot.  I have tried to do this by writing domap2 as a macro, but the way that the catch-all variable after `&` is handled keeps tripping me up, as illustrated above.

Other examples (out of 15 or 20 different versions), benchmark code, and times on a Macbook Pro that's a few years old (full source [here](https://github.com/mars0i/popco-x/blob/master/test/popco/domaptest.clj)):

```
(defn domap1
  [f coll]
  (doseq [e coll] 
    (f e)))

(defn domap7
  [f coll]
  (dorun (map f coll)))

(defn domap18
  [f & colls]
  (dorun (apply map f colls)))

(defn domap15
  [f coll] 
  (when (seq coll)
    (f (first coll))
    (recur f (rest coll))))

(defn domap17
  [f & colls]
  (let [argvecs (apply (partial map vector) colls)] ; seq of ntuples of interleaved vals
    (doseq [args argvecs]
      (apply f args))))
```

I'm working on an application that uses core.matrix matrices and vectors, but feel free to substitute your own side-effecting functions below.

```
(ns tst
  (:use criterium.core
        [clojure.core.matrix :as mx]))

(def howmany 1000)
(def a-coll (vec (range howmany)))
(def maskvec (zero-vector :vectorz howmany))

(defn unmaskit!
  [idx]
  (mx/mset! maskvec idx 1.0)) ; sets element idx of maskvec to 1.0

(defn runbench
  [domapfn label]
  (print (str "\n" label ":\n"))
  (bench (def _ (domapfn unmaskit! a-coll))))
```

Mean execution times according to Criterium, in microseconds:

domap1:   12.317551 [doseq]
domap2:   19.065317 [dotimes]
domap3:  265.983779 [dotimes with apply, map]
domap7:   53.263230 [map with dorun]
domap18:  54.456801 [map with dorun, multiple collections]
domap15:  32.034993 [recur]
domap17:  95.259984 [doseq, multiple collections interleaved using map]

EDIT: It may be that `dorun`+`map` is the best way to implement `domap` for multiple large lazy sequence arguments, but `doseq` is still king when it comes to single lazy sequences.  Performing the same operation as `unmask!` above, but running the index through `(mod idx 1000)`, and iterating over `(range 100000000)`, `doseq` is about twice as fast as `dorun`+`map` in my tests (i.e. `(def domap25 (comp dorun map))`).

Comment: Your actual question of "How to write variadic Clojure macro that takes collections as arguments" is totally lost. Consider editing to just the parts relevant to the actual question.

Comment: Thanks @A.Webb .  Moved main question information to the top.  I expected folks to try to steer me away from the question, as you have.  I don't mind that, but so far it seems to me that it's worth answering for my case.  I've now added additional versions of `domap` with timings in the "appendix" section.  As you can see, dorun+map (`domap7` and `domap8`) is much slower than `doseq` (`domap1`) and `dotimes` (`domap2` and `domap3`).  (I resorted to `dotimes` because I couldn't figure out a more efficient way to walk collections in parallel (see `domap15` and `domap17`).)

Comment: I edited and replaced domap8 with domap18, and replaced times after a new test.  domap8 had used `apply (partial map f)`.  You reminded me that I can just say `apply map f` instead.

Comment: One more thing: I agree--I would think that `dotimes` would be slow.  Maybe I just haven't tried it on long enough collections.  There should be a way to make a multiple-collection version that's as fast as the single-collection `doseq` version.

Comment: Since I posted this question and it was answered, [`run!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!) has been added to the core language.  It doesn't quite do what I wanted, but it's related and it's worthwhile to know about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a macro, and I don't see why a macro would be helpful here.

```
user> (defn do-map [f & lists] (apply mapv f lists) nil)
#'user/do-map
user> (do-map (comp println +) (range 2 6) (range 8 11) (range 22 40))
32
35
38
nil
```

note do-map here is eager (thanks to mapv) and only executes for side effects

Macros can use varargs lists, as the (useless!) macro version of do-map demonstrates:

```
user> (defmacro do-map-macro [f & lists] `(do (mapv ~f ~@lists) nil))
#'user/do-map-macro
user> (do-map-macro (comp println +) (range 2 6) (range 8 11) (range 22 40))
32
35
38
nil
user> (macroexpand-1 '(do-map-macro (comp println +) (range 2 6) (range 8 11) (range 22 40)))
(do (clojure.core/mapv (comp println +) (range 2 6) (range 8 11) (range 22 40)) nil)
```

**Addendum:**
addressing the efficiency / garbage-creation concerns:
note that below I truncate the output of the criterium bench function, for conciseness reasons:

```
(defn do-map-loop
  [f & lists]
  (loop [heads lists]
    (when (every? seq heads)
      (apply f (map first heads))
      (recur (map rest heads)))))


user> (crit/bench (with-out-str (do-map-loop (comp println +) (range 2 6) (range 8 11) (range 22 40))))
...
            Execution time mean : 11.367804 µs
...
```

This looks promising because it doesn't create a data structure that we aren't using anyway (unlike mapv above). But it turns out it is slower than the previous (maybe because of the two map calls?).

```
user> (crit/bench (with-out-str (do-map-macro (comp println +) (range 2 6) (range 8 11) (range 22 40))))
...
             Execution time mean : 7.427182 µs
...
user> (crit/bench (with-out-str (do-map (comp println +) (range 2 6) (range 8 11) (range 22 40))))
...
             Execution time mean : 8.355587 µs
...
```

Since the loop still wasn't faster, let's try a version which specializes on arity, so that we don't need to call map twice on every iteration:

```
(defn do-map-loop-3
  [f a b c]
  (loop [[a & as] a
         [b & bs] b
         [c & cs] c]
    (when (and a b c)
      (f a b c)
      (recur as bs cs))))
```

Remarkably, though this is faster, it is still slower than the version that just used mapv:

```
user> (crit/bench (with-out-str (do-map-loop-3 (comp println +) (range 2 6) (range 8 11) (range 22 40))))
...
             Execution time mean : 9.450108 µs
...
```

Next I wondered if the size of the input was a factor. With larger inputs...

```
user> (def test-input (repeatedly 3 #(range (rand-int 100) (rand-int 1000))))
#'user/test-input
user> (map count test-input)
(475 531 511)
user> (crit/bench (with-out-str (apply do-map-loop-3 (comp println +) test-input)))
...
            Execution time mean : 1.005073 ms
...
user> (crit/bench (with-out-str (apply do-map (comp println +) test-input)))
...
             Execution time mean : 756.955238 µs
...
```

Finally, for completeness, the timing of do-map-loop (which as expected is slightly slower than do-map-loop-3)

```
user> (crit/bench (with-out-str (apply do-map-loop (comp println +) test-input)))
...
             Execution time mean : 1.553932 ms
```

As we see, even with larger input sizes, mapv is faster.

(I should note for completeness here that map is slightly faster than mapv, but not by a large degree).

Comment: I am thinking there is a subquestion here about doing a mapping over mulitple collections for side effects efficiently, and am working on a benchmarked optimized verion (also not a macro).

Comment: There's (too) many subquestions here, but one was also how to do it without creating the whole sequence. I think your `mapv` does, though you discard it at the end by returning `nil`. `(dorun (apply map f colls))` would not.

Comment: Excellent @noisesmith.  This takes 23 millisecs on my test, about the same as the `dotimes` version, and doesn't risk blowing up on long collections.  It looks like the macro version avoids the problem I had with varargs because `mapv` already expects variable numbers of collections.

Comment: An initial version had apply instead of the unquote-splicing, which should help in this case. When I am done benchmarking I will post the non-garbage-making version.

Comment: @Mars, I still would consider the code by A. Webb, as it does not seem to create the returned applied sequence that is ignored.

Comment: @noisemith re subqueston about mapping over multiple collections for side-effects, I just asked a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465864/efficient-way-to-walk-collections-in-parallel-with-doseq) about whether there's a way to force `doseq` to do this.  I don't see how, and await your code.  Thanks.

Comment: @A.Webb, sorry about the complexity of the question.  I appreciate folks being willing to go through it all.  I had come to feel I had to resort to a macro that did something odd, so I felt I had to explain why.  That opens the whole can of worms: I end up in effect asking about the original problem that prompted the macro question as well.

Comment: A.Webb: regarding your assertion that the collection does not get created with (dorun (map ...)) my timings do not support that at all, it is in fact just slightly faster than mapv (~723µs for the larger data set) and not nearly in the league of the loop based solution

Comment: noisesmith, wow, thanks for doing all that work.  Wonderful.  Questions of clarification: Where you say "the version that just used map", I think you mean "mapv"; this is an important distinction, since `map` is what everyone would naturally use, but you've pointed out that `mapv` is faster.  At the end you say that the loop version is faster for large inputs, but the timings you report show the opposite, as do my own tests.

Comment: OK, I got the milli / micro reversed! definitely a facepalm mistake, will need to edit.

Comment: @noisesmith That comment was about maximum space consumption, not time used nor even garbage created. Using `mapv` would realize the whole sequence, `O(n)` space, before discarding it. Using `(dorun (map ... ))` would realize only a piece at a time, `O(1)`, not holding onto the head. I would expect a highly tailored loop to perform better.

Comment: A. Webb: funny enough, map turned out faster, I was misreading the benchmark output (I am not used to the greek letters), I just updated to reflect this.

Comment: and you are right, the heap space would be less with map than with mapv.

Comment: noisesmith, @A.Webb , does it seem inappropriate at this point to simply delete the part of the original question about how to handle the variadic macro (possibly asking that in a separate question)? Then I could mark noisesmith's answer as the correct answer, which is deserved.  A.Webb, you're right, the question includes too much, and the answer and comments have addressed the underlying question about tradeoffs for writing `domap`; that has become the de facto focus of this question.  Thanks to both of you as well as Diego Sevilla.

Comment: I addressed the variadic macro issue I think, `(defmacro do-map-macro [f & lists] `(do (mapv ~f ~@lists) nil))` - or am I missing the actual question here?

Comment: You showed a variadic macro in a simpler case.  I still can't figure out how to do what I originally was trying to do.  It's very tricky to get the macro working with `dotimes`, unless I'm just skipping over an obvious way to do it.  Everything I try fails, for one reason or another. That's the question that I would split off into a separate question, maybe. You deserve the checkmark, but that question hasn't been answered. (I no longer want to write such a macro, but I'm still curious about how to do it.) Just a question of whether to do major surgery for the sake of people who come by later.