# Efficient way to walk collections in parallel with doseq (or for)?

Tags: clojure

```
(doseq [e coll1]
  (myfunc e))
```

is very fast, if all you care about are side effects.  What if I want `myfunc` to take elements from multiple collections "in parallel", i.e. apply `myfunc` to the first elements of each collection, then to all of the second elements, then to all of the third elements, etc.?  Note that this is as much a question about the functionality of `for` as `doseq`, but if one wants a sequence as output, `map` will do what's needed, so `for` isn't necessary.

```
(doseq [e1 coll1
        e2 coll2]
   (myfunc e1 e2))
```

will instead apply `myfunc` to all possible combinations of elements from the two collections.  If I know in advance what the elements of the collection will be, I could use a `:when` test to combine only certain elements, but suppose that I don't know that?

One solution is to create ntuples to avoid the Cartesian product, but that is time consuming, removing the speed advantage of using `doseq` in the first place:

```
(let [argvecs (map vector coll1 coll2)] ; seq of ntuples of interleaved vals
  (doseq [args argvecs]
     (apply myfunc args))))
```

(This can be about 8X slower than a single-collection `doseq`.  See times for `domap1` and `domap17` at the end of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449549/how-to-write-variadic-clojure-macro-that-takes-collections-as-arguments/21465689?noredirect=1#21465689).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid the overhead of creating tuples with map, all you can do is write it yourself, as a loop/recur that walks each collection manually. But really, you'll still end up needing to create a tuple so that you can `(apply f args)`, where `args` is the nth item of each collection. You'll save a few cons cells by not making a list of such tuples, but that's all. A lot of the expense of variadic functions like this is calling `apply`, and building the lists to do that with. You can avoid that by writing a 2-arity version of your doseq-sibling, and a 3-arity, and... But the n-arity version will always be slower.

Comment: Useful points about `apply`--thanks.  In experiments I've done with `recur` (see link in the question), it's slower than `doseq` on a single collection, so I wouldn't expect it to be better than a parallel-iteration `doseq`.

Comment: In the other question this split off from I benchmarked a targetted arity vs. varargs comparison with loop/recur and there was a ~150% performance difference. The difference in performance between loop/recur and dorun map on large collections was extreme.

Comment: One day I might copy the `doseq` source, strip out code for complex `for` options like `:while`, and make it iterate in parallel without doing a Cartesian product.  One day.  Maybe.  Looks pretty hairy to me at present.  I may never learn that much about Clojure guts.

Comment: I think the main thing that makes `doseq` fast is that it's optimized for chunked sequences, a feature that doesn't really translate to walking multiple collections in parallel. I'm not sure you'll be able to get any benefit from such an effort.

Answer (score 3):

If it's speed you're after you should turn on [reflection-warnings](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/%2awarn-on-reflection%2a) and maybe check out the [loop-primitive](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/loop) (recuring with (rest coll1) (rest coll2))...

also checkout [Clojure is still](http://www.learningclojure.com/2013/02/clojure-is-fast-is-clojure-still-fast.html) fast and the performance testing framework [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) to make sure you are measuring the right thing.

Comment: Thanks claj.  I'll look into those resources.  Yes, good; I always do speed tests with Criterium.  Don't leave home without it.

Comment: claj, is there a typo in the links in your answer?  'loop-primitive' points to the same page as 'reflection-warnings'.

Comment: I believe that the performance of `loop`/`recur` will be similar to `recur`ing to the top-level function.  `doseq` appears to be faster than the latter (see other question linked in above question).  My guess is that it's faster because of the way that it chunks pieces of sequences. (I'm guessing here--I don't really understand this part of the source for `doseq`.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, this is what `map` does:

```
(map + [1 2] [3 4])
; => (4 6)
```

If you want that just for effects, you can use `dorun` in the resulting map:

```
(dorun (map (comp println +) [1 2] [3 4]))
; => nil
```

Comment: Ah yes, I should have mentioned that.  Of course that does the same thing, but it's more than 4X slower than `doseq` on a single collection, so doesn't seem like the most efficient solution for multiple collections.  It turns out that `mapv` is quite fast, as noisesmith's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449549/how-to-write-variadic-clojure-macro-that-takes-collections-as-arguments/21465689?noredirect=1#21465689) shows, but still not as fast as `doseq`.

Comment: Mmm... Looking at the (wonderful) `doseq` implementation, it seems that it is optimized for different types of collections. Could you repeat your tests with non-indexed collections (like lists) and see if this is the case? Looking at the `doseq` code seems to me that the `dorun` alternative should work as fast as the doseq when the collection is not indexable at O(1).

Comment: Good idea.  I had been passing in a PersistentVector.  Just tried it with a LazySeq and then with a PersistentList: Each time `doseq` was still much faster than `map` with `dorun` in my tests (length of collection: 1000, side-effecting function sets an element in a core.matrix vectorz vector, where the element is chosen by the integer from the collection).  (In A. Webb's tests, with longer collections and a slower side effect, I gather, there's much less of a difference.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `(dorun (map f coll1 coll2 ..))` or `(dorun (map apply f colls))`.

The more you ask of `f`, the longer it is going to take.

```
(def a (atom 0)
(defn f [& args] (swap! a #(apply + % args)))
(def N 10000)
```

On a single collection use `doseq`. There is avoidable overhead from the lazy-seq structure.

```
(bench (doseq [e (range N)] (f e)))
Execution time mean : 4.959713 ms

(bench (dorun (map f (range N))))
Execution time mean : 5.669721 ms
```

On two collections, note `f` has to add twice instead of once, so I would *expect* this to take twice as long. Note now *both* versions have some structural overhead.

```
(bench (let [argvecs (map vector (range N) (range N))] 
  (doseq [e argvecs] (apply f e))))
Execution time mean : 11.876843 ms

(bench (dorun (map f (range N) (range N))))
Execution time mean : 11.145435 ms
```

Comment: Thanks A. Webb.  I can see that with your `f`, `doseq` and `dorun map` are a lot closer than the times I was getting with my function  my other recent question, in which you also provided helpful comments.