# Clojure variadic macro iterating over sequences collected in & extra parameter

Tags: macros, clojure

Problem: How to handle a catch-all parameter after `&` in a macro, when the arguments to be passed are sequences, and the catch-all variable needs to be dealt with as a sequence of sequences?  What gets listed in the catch-all variable are literal expressions.

This is a macro that's intended to behave roughly Common Lisp's `mapc`, i.e. to do what Clojure's `map` does, but *only* for side-effects, and without laziness:

```
(defmacro domap [f & colls] 
      `(dotimes [i# (apply min (map count '(~@colls)))]
         (apply ~f (map #(nth % i#) '(~@colls)))))
```

I've come to realize that this is not a good way to write `domap`--I got good advice about that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449549/efficient-side-effect-only-analogue-of-clojures-map-function) question.  However, I'm still wondering about the tricky macro problem that I encountered along the way.

This works if the collection is passed as a literal:

```
user=> (domap println [0 1 2])
0
1
2
nil
```

But doesn't work in other situations like this one:

```
user=> (domap println (range 3))
range
3
nil
```

Or this one:

```
user=> (def nums [0 1 2])
#'user/nums
user=> (domap println nums)
UnsupportedOperationException count not supported on this type: Symbol clojure.lang.RT.countFro (RT.java:556)
```

The problem is that it's literal expressions that are inside `colls`.  This is why the macro `domap` works when passed a sequence of integers, but not in other situations.  Notice the instances of `'(nums)`:

```
user=> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(domap println nums)))
(clojure.core/dotimes
 [i__199__auto__
  (clojure.core/apply
   clojure.core/min
   (clojure.core/map clojure.core/count '(nums)))]
 (clojure.core/apply
  println
  (clojure.core/map
   (fn*
    [p1__198__200__auto__]
    (clojure.core/nth p1__198__200__auto__ i__199__auto__))
   '(nums))))
```

I've tried various combinations of `~`, `~@`, `'`, `let` with `var#`, etc.  Nothing's worked.  Maybe it's a mistake to try to write this as a macro, but I'd still be curious how to write a variadic macro that takes complex arguments like these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is why your macro does not work:

`'(~@colls)` This expression creates a quoted list of all colls. E. g. if you pass it `(range 3)`, this expression becomes `'((range 3))`, so the *literal* argument will be one of your colls, preventing evaluation of `(range 3)` certainly not what you want here.

Now if you would not quote `(~@colls)` inside the macro, of course they would become a literal function invocation like `((range 3))`, which makes the compiler throw after macroexpansion time (it will try to eval `((0 1 2))`).

You can use `list` to avoid this problem:

```
(defmacro domap [f & colls]
  `(dotimes [i# (apply min (map count (list ~@colls)))]
     (apply ~f (map #(nth % i#) (list ~@colls)))))

=> (domap println (range 3))
0
1
2
```

However one thing here is terrible: Inside the macro, the entire list is created *twice*. Here is how we could avoid that:

```
(defmacro domap [f & colls]
  `(let [colls# (list ~@colls)]
     (dotimes [i# (apply min (map count colls#))]
       (apply ~f (map #(nth % i#) colls#)))))
```

The colls are not the only thing that we need to prevent from being evaluated multiple times. If the user passes something like `(fn [& args] ...)` as `f`, that lambda would also be compiled in every step.

Now this is the exactly the scenario where you should ask yourself why you are writing a macro. Essentially, your macro has to make sure all arguments are eval'd without transforming them in any way before. Evaluation comes gratis with functions, so let's write it as a function instead:

```
(defn domap [f & colls]
  (dotimes [i (apply min (map count colls))]
    (apply f (map #(nth % i) colls))))
```

Given what you want to achieve, notice there is a function to solve that already, `dorun` which simply realizes a seq but does not retain the `head`. E. g.:

```
`(dorun (map println (range 3)))
```

would do the trick as well.

Now that you have `dorun` and `map`, you can simply compose them using `comp` to achieve your goal:

```
(def domap (comp dorun map))

=> (domap println (range 3) (range 10) (range 3))

0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks--Just what I wanted.  I didn't expect that an explicit call to `list` would be necessary--I think of backquote as syntactic sugar for `(list ...)`.  Thanks for the point about multiple evaluation of the function--had been wondering about that.  Although `dorun` + `map` is the natural way to do what I'm trying to do, I want to note that it's not always fastest (see question linked from my question).  If one did want to prevent multiple evaluation of a function similar to this one, would adding `f# ~f` inside the `let` bindings, and replacing `~f` with `f#` after `apply` accomplish that?

Comment: Yes, binding f once to a generated symbol would solve the issue. However even in the discussion below the the answer you linked to A. Webb states correctly that `dorun` performs at O(1) in space complexity because only the head is held in memory. Generating a loop from a macro may run faster, but the per-step overhead should be very, very little. In comparison to noisesmiths benchmarks please benchmark (`comp dorun map)`

Comment: I very much appreciate the help I'm getting, and the macro in my question performs terribly, but: it's frustrating to be repeatedly told that `dorun` + `map` is *the* solution.  It depends.  It is the easiest way to do what I want, but .... I have been benchmarking the heck out of this, and I know that's not always fastest. `(comp dorun map)`: 54 microsecs iterating through a single 1000-element vector, using each element as an index into a vectorz-clj vector. Noisesmith's `mapv` definition: 20-22 micsecs, `doseq`: 19 micsecs, `recur`: 35 micsecs, simple `dotimes`: 19 micsecs. Others worse.

Comment: correction: `doseq` takes 12-13 microsecs.  (And for anyone who hasn't read the other question (why should you have?), yes, I'm using Criterium.)

Comment: This most likely is because `seq` is invoked on the input sequence. `doseq` uses chunked sequences which will work faster on a vector. `doseq` is certainly the most idiomatic way of traversing one sequence for side-effects. On vectors it should perform almost the same as `dotimes` on a vector (looking up the indices) which should be the closest you can get to O(1). I provided `dorun+map` because you asked for a `mapc` equivalent. `mapv` creates a sequence of the results, so I would never recommend to use it only for side-effects.

Comment: Regarding `'`, it's not syntactic sugar around `list` but a literal translating to `quote`. `quote` is a special form that tells the evaluator "don't eval".

Comment: About `dorun`+`map`: thanks, I understand. Backquote, OK, got it.  (I just tried `doseq` vs. `dorun+map` on `(range 100000000)`, btw; `doseq` is about twice as fast. I think Clojure should have a chunked `mapc`, but I may be the only person who thinks this!  Might advocate for that on the Google group.  I don't know enough to repurpose chunking code in Clojure source--don't understand it.)

Comment: `f` is NOT compiled multiple times in his original code, only evaluated multiple times. That's definitely bad, of course, since it can come from some expensive function, but very different from multiple compilation.

Comment: @amalloy: Thanks. Would you care to elaborate why?

Comment: Because lambdas are compiled only once, at compile time, and never at run time. A macro that expanded like `(~f (~f (~f x#)))` would compile `f` three times, because it would be expanded into three unrelated lambdas. But the `doseq` in his post only contains one lambda, so it is only compiled once.

Comment: No, the form passed to his macro as `f` will end up in a loop form generated by the `dotimes` he uses and then be compiled with each step.

Comment: The lambda passed to map will also be compiled with each step.

Comment: No, that is simply not how things work. `dotimes` expands to a form that contains `f` only once, so `f` is compiled only once. The same applies to the lambda passed to `map`. Both are *evaluated* many times, but that's just a call to `new`/`malloc`, which is roughly a zillion times cheaper than a call to the compiler.

Comment: Just because the form is *read* once it does not mean it or parts of it are compiled once. Both lambdas are not evaluated before they end up in the `loop` form. `loop` is a special form and thus, like macros receives them unevaluated. `loop` now needs to compile them at each step as they could enclose e.g. looping variables. In contrast, the lambda passed to map will be evaluated (at each `loop` iteration) as part of the form `(map ...)`. That is because `map` is a function invocation. The `map` process receives a compiled function object that it can reuse in each of its iterations.

Comment: Shortly put: `loop` evaluates, `fn` compiles. I originally thought you were referring to some analyzer/optimization where `fn` forms are hashed that I now realize is not possible (or is it?).

Comment: I'd like to edit but can't anymore so for more precision/less text: `loop` evaluates the forms in it in context of the lexical binding. Evaluating the `fn` forms then results in compilation. `recur` will induce repetition of that.